# I have no knowledge beyond html. How do I make this form work?

Tags: mysql, database, forms, submit

So, I'm making a couple changes to a website, since my boss is cheap and does not want to pay anyone to do it.

I am trying to add a form on a web page that lets a user type in a first and last name.  They will then get a page saying verified with a picture of the person if they are in the database.  Or, they will receive a page with a message that the person is unknown.

This is for the general public to verify if someone who represented our company is a valid employee or not.

So, what I have so far is the following code, which I am competant enough to put together to style the form (computer class 10+ years ago).  But I have NOOOOO IDEA where to go from here.  Please help me, and assume I am clueless, because I am! :)

```
<div class="sidebar_right_bottom">
    <h3>Rep Verification</h3>
    <div class="login_form">
        <p><center>Enter the name of the rep who contacted you to verify their identity.</center></p>
        <form>
            <div>
                <span><label>First Name</label></span>
                <span><input name="userfirstname" type="text" class="textbox"></span>
            </div>
            <div>
                <span><label>Last Name</label></span>
                <span><input name="userlastname" type="text" class="textbox"></span>
            </div>
            <div>
                <span><input type="submit" class="mybutton" value="Submit"></span>
            </div>
        </form>
        </br>
    </div>
</div>
        </div>
<div class="clear">
```

This is what the code generates using css:

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

So, now... I have a styled form on the page, how do I get it to submit, check against a database, and return a page with the info on it for the user?

More Info:

We bought the domain through godaddy and have simply bought the cpanel hosting and written basic html.  I am attaching screenshots of what I have access to:
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/byzyZ.jpg)[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/upIDv.jpg)

Also, I don't know if this helps:
Server: Localhost via UNIX socket
Server type: MySQL
Server version: 5.5.42-cll-lve - MySQL Community Server (GPL)
Protocol version: 10
Server charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)

Sorry for being so clueless here...

Comment: You have an extra `</div>`. And `</br>` is written like this: `<br/>`.

Comment: This question is extremely broad and not really suitable for the SO format, where we try to help with specific, well-defined problems. Your solution will involve server-side scripting (what technology is powering the website now?), database SQL queries etc (which will depend on your database schema) and so on.

Comment: Asking someone without any serverside knowledge to execute this kind of task seems a bit *too cheap*.

Answer (score 0):

in Form tag add

```
<Form method="POST" action="test.xxx">
```

That way when someone push submit button the request will go to test.xxx site. Now you will only need to create a serverside script to check the database.
Unfortunately we do not know anything about your server so we do not know if it runs php, java or anything else. Please post that information and information about your database so we can help.

Edit: In that case, from your image i suspect you may have php. But there is still some information we need. 
Create on server a file, name it : test.php

inside of this file paste this code:

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

And redirect your webbrowser to this file.
If you have php installed you'll see a bunch of tables with a lot of info. We could use php version and mysql connection type. You can search for pdo and mysqli :)

Answer (score 0):

In your  tag, you will need to specify the action and method when the submit button is clicked. You would like to visit this website on how submitting works.[W3School Form](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp)